# How to redirect network traffic to a user space program?

Tags: networking

I'd like to redirect the operating system's network traffic to a program. The program needs to receive all outbound traffic and be able to produce inbound traffic, acting as a virtual network interface of sort. Since I'd be doing it for demonstration purposes, performance and security are not my concerns. Instead, I'm mainly after the simplest available solution for either Windows or Linux, whichever would be easier to work with.

I've already looked at NetAdapterCx, but I've got zero experience with driver development for Windows, and quickly got overwhelmed by the amount of code in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/NetAdapter-Cx-Driver-Samples) official example. I'm interested in learning more about driver development, but since this is not the main goal of the project, I'd prefer something with a shallower learning curve.

As far as the protocol layer is concerned, the program would ideally be operating at the MAC layer, handling layer 2 frames, and delegating higher layers to the system.

In case this isn't the right site for the question, please point me to the appropriate one.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center. As for the correct community, there is one, at least for your question in its current form. Software development is out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: Well probably something like what OpenVPN uses: tun/tap interface.

Comment: do you actually need to intercept/capture/replay the traffic, or do you just need visibility to it?

Comment: @FrankThomas I need to intercept the traffic. Communication with external hosts should happen through the application. The application will manage the physical connection which won't rely on the computer's networking hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound would this question be better suited for Stack Overflow?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tuntap.html

Comment: @Cosinux - My comment was supposed to say “there isn’t one”. This question would not be well received on Stack Overflow